# Javascript - Accessing object

Tags: javascript

I have the following data object

```
var data = {
  labels: ["2013", "2014", "2015", "2016"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Label 1", 
      data: data1,
    }, 
    {
      label: "Label 2", 
      data: data2, 
    }
  ]
};
```

I want to get the second label "Label 2".

I have tried to use

```
console.log(data.datasets[0].label); // Only returns Label 1
console.log(data.datasets[0][1].label); // Doesn't work
```

I don't want to make changes on the structure as I am using it with Chart.js to draw charts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `console.log(data.datasets[1].label);` ..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access it like this:

```
console.log( data.datasets[1].label );
```

<sup>Example: https://jsfiddle.net/55ex0p80/</sup>

Let's break it down into four steps:

```
data.datasets[ 1 ].label
|    |         |  |
1    2         3  4
|    |         |  \- The field "label" of the object
|    |         \---- The desired key of the array called "datasets"
|    \-------------- The array called "datasets"
\------------------- The data object
```

This way you end up at the label field you were looking for:

```
var data = {             <---- step 1
  labels: ["2013", "2014", "2015", "2016"],
  datasets: [            <---- step 2
    {
      label: "Label 1", 
      data: data1,
    }, 
    {                    <---- step 3
      label: "Label 2",  <---- step 4
      data: data2, 
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

- `data = {}` is an object
- `labels =["2013","2014",...]` is an array of strings
- `datasets = [{},{},{}]` is an array of objects

Thus for accessing `'Label 2'` you need to access 2nd object of the datasets array and then access its label as: `data.datasets[1].label`